# Why are we always assuming normality?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

For a great number of statistical testing (ANOVA or discriminant analysis for example), we suppose that the variables follow a normal law. How many times did I see this supposition ?

But I recently learnt that we could calculate the [Kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) (the measure of the "tailedness") and the [Skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) of the variables and check if they both followed the normal value (1 for the kurtosis, and 0 for the skewness). But before that, I always made the assumption that my variables followed a normal law, without testing it.

Is this because I am a student, and I just have to apply the theorem and calculus I learn during my scholartime, or is it just because we always assume our variables follow normal law?

Furthermore, one of my professor just told me that with a great amount of data (~ >= 1 million), we just assume that the variables and its moment estimators follow a normal law. But when I calculated my kurtosis and skewness, I found enormous values, sometimes greater than 100. To me, it means my variables DOESN'T follow a normal law. So why my professor assume it does?

I apology for my poor English, and I hope my question is clear nonetheless.

Comment: The Central limit theorem shows why the normal distribution is so essential in statistics.

Comment: Depending on context, normality assumption in statistics is often made simply for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple questions that you ask. In general, assuming normality is plain wrong, a random variable could be whatever (exponential, Pareto, beta, gamma). In the same sense if you have some data it could be that they come from a particular distribution or that they are "random" or deterministic.

About the skewness and kurtosis, you can calculate them and see if they match those of a normal distribution, be aware this matching does not mean that your data come from a normal distribution necessarily. Finally, any amount of data does not allow you to assume normality
(why would it?), most probably your professor was talking about the [Central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which says something totally different.

On a high level the Central limit theorem says : If you have a population with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and take sufficiently large random samples from the population with replacement, then the distribution of the sample means will be approximately normally distributed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: You are welcome but if you think it answers your question please accept it as an answer.